# Custom GTM JS variable issue

Tags: javascript, variables, google-tag-manager

I am trying to pull the text from the drop-down menu selection. If I use

`document.getElementById("c6bf8c48-f2d9-eb11-bacb-00224804ce17").value`

I get the numerical value of the selection. How I can get a text value?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try `document.getElementById("c6bf8c48-f2d9-eb11-bacb-00224804ce17").innerHTML`

Comment: innerText will work as well. For this scenario I think innerText might be a better option if we only want the text